# Depending on answer sent to different email

Tags: php, email, conditional-statements

I need to add a condition. If the `$contact_subject` is bigger than the number 50000, it should go to one email-address and if it's smaller it should go to another email-address.

```
if( $contact_name == true )
{
    $sender = $contact_email;
    $receiver = "email@email.com";
    $client_ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $email_body = "Name: $contact_name \nEmail: $sender \nAccount Number: $contact_subject \nMessage: $contact_message \nIP: $client_ip \nEmail Sent from website http://www.website.com";      
    $extra = "From: $sender\r\n" . "Reply-To: $sender \r\n" . "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion();

    if( mail( $receiver, "Email From Website - $subject", $email_body, $extra ) ) 
    {
        echo "success=yes";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "success=no";
    }
}
```

Comment: have you tried just using an if....elseif statement?

Comment: I am not really good at this. I will work with the suggestion from Amal.

Comment: Will let you know asap Amal.

Answer (score 1):

Use a ternary statement to check if `$contact_subject` is greater than 50000 and set the `$receiver` email address depending on the condition.

```
$receiver = ($contact_subject > 50000) ? 'abc@example.com' : 'xyz@example.com';
```

The same can be accomplished using an [`if-else`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php) block too.

```
if ($contact_subject > 50000) {
    $receiver = 'abc@example.com';
}
else {
    $receiver = 'xyz@example.com';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe better way is put size in variable number.

```
-> config.php
    $size_mail = '5000';


-> mail.php
include "config.php";
if( $contact_name == true )
    {

    if($contact_subject > $size_mail)
    {$receiver = 'mailone@nobody.com';}else{$receiver == 'mailtwo@nobody.com';}

        $sender = $contact_email;
        $client_ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
        $email_body = "Name: $contact_name \nEmail: $sender \nAccount Number: $contact_subject \nMessage: $contact_message \nIP: $client_ip \nEmail Sent from website http://www.website.com";      
        $extra = "From: $sender\r\n" . "Reply-To: $sender \r\n" . "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion();

        if( mail( $receiver, "Email From Website - $subject", $email_body, $extra ) ) 
        {
            echo "success=yes";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "success=no";
        }
    }
```

Comment: You guys rock! Thank you so much! I will try that. I am not very good at this so I really appreciate the quick response and help!!